# Replace string with $ from makefile with sed

Tags: sed, makefile

I am trying to replace `${dbPassword}` in a property file with a password including `$` signs.

My command is the following, but I have no idea how to replace this properly.

```
run: @cat $(FILE_PATH) | sed -i .bak 's/$${dbPassword}/$(VARIABLE_WITH_PWD)/g' $(FILE_PATH)
```

Let's say my dbPassword is: `123$456$789`

With this, I am getting the result:  `123${dbPassword}456${dbPassword}789`

Comment: Do I understand this right: you want to replace the literal string `${dbPassword}`, and not the value it expands to?

Comment: And can you show contents of the file before and after your command? Does there happen to be a `&` character in the real password?

Comment: yep I just wanted to update the text the originally has a &

Comment: Can you add representative contents of the file before your change, and the desired end result, as well as an example password that contains all the same special characters as your real password?

Comment: You still haven't given us. [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This is important (in this case) because it's not clear how the variable `VARIABLE_WITH_PWD` gets its value, or that it has the value you think it has. If we *assume* it has the correct value, you may find that the solutions we give don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Three problems:

1. Target and recipe on the same line. The recipe must be on the next line, indented with a hard tab.
2. You pass `$(FILE_PATH)` on stdin, *and* as a file argument to sed. Remove the cat pipe.
3. Shell variables (as opposed to make variables) are not substituted inside single quotes.

So you might want to try this instead:

```
.PHONY: run
run:
        sed -i .bak "s/$${dbPassword}/$(VARIABLE_WITH_PWD)/g" $(FILE_PATH)
```

This assumes you have an environment variable, `dbPassword` and exported it prior to running `make`. If that is not the case, please provide your complete makefile.

I also have removed the `@` so you actually see what command `make` is executing. There's no point in wearing a blindfold while debugging your makefile.